# Python script to print tooltip value when mouse is over a property

Tags: python, properties, drivers

I want to get the tooltip value of a property when the mouse is over it (after pressing a shortcut), like the X location of an object or another value that can be animated in the scene.

In specific, I need the full data path of a property to automate the creation of a specific driver configuration.

I've tried to get the information from the right-click menu or the tooltip, but it doesn't seem to be accessible with python. For instance the path marked in green.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

For recent Blender builds (daily builds), you can do this using shortcuts.

See: https://www.blender.org/manual/interface/buttons_and_controls.html#common-shortcuts

---

- <kbd>Ctrl-Shift-C</kbd> - copy the data-path for this property
  *(also available from the right-click menu).*
  Useful when writing drivers or scripts.
- <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-Shift-C</kbd> - copy the **full** data-path for this data-block and property.

**Warning:** This is typically bad practice when scripting, in most cases its best to access values based on `bpy.context`, accessing via string lookups in `bpy.data` is error prone since the user may rename objects.

Comment: I think this is a fair warning, and still being able to do this is a comfortable convenience in those scenarios (to demo, to experiment) where using the path directly is perfectly fine.