# What's the usage of "Set/Get property" nodes in sverchok

Tags: sverchok

I found there is no **input/output socket** for this two nodes:
[image: Set/Get Node]  
So I don't know how to use them....  
I guess the original node is [Eval Knieval](http://nikitron.cc.ua/sverch/html/nodes/scene/eval_knieval.html), and it was divided into two seperate nodes:
[image: Eval Knieval Nodes] 
But where is the **input/output sockets**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was indeed derived from Eval Knieval node, but we felt it was cleaner to have dedicated nodes for In and Out instead of a multi-purpose node that switches its outward appearance.

For Get and Set it's shockingly simple, you paste/type the attribute path you want to control and the node automatically detects what kind of Socket to add.

[image]

Comment: Last question at BSE...How to copy full data path quickly without typing?

Comment: or upvote this question: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39564/python-script-to-print-tooltip-value-when-mouse-is-over-a-property

Comment: Still related to this topic, but kind of wanted generic data from Sverchok to AN. Ok, in Sverchok, I use GET and SET. In AN, I use script node.

Supposed I am using petal_sine.py Script node, and I like the Verts List output and want to just pipe this into AN.

I type this in AN Script node:

vector_out = bpy.data.node_groups['SVNT'].nodes['Script Generator'].outputs[0]

And I am getting none.

Comment: ask a new question @BlenderSushiGuy , the stackexchange comments section isn't for QA. or ask on sverchok issue tracker.